# How to simplify this summation equation?

Tags: calculus

If I have

$$
\sum_{n=1}^K nx^{n-1} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1-x^{K+1}}{1-x}.
$$

How to calculate this formula based on above equation ?

$$a = \sum_{n=2}^{K}n\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)^{n-1}\rho^n$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Factor out $\rho$ and put it outside the summation. $$a = \sum_{n=2}^{K}n\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)^{n-1}\rho^n = \rho\sum_{n=2}^{K}n\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)^{n-1}\rho^{n-1}=\rho\left(\left(\sum_{n=1}^{K}n\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)^{n-1}\rho^{n-1}\right)-1\right)$$

Comment: It doesn't matter if n=2, not n=1?

Comment: No, but you can add 1 and subtract 1 from the summation. @Urise

Comment: I have edited my answer. @Urise

Comment: What happens if I change like this? $$a = \sum_{n=2}^{K}(n-2)\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)^{n-1}\rho^n$$

Answer (score 0):

$$a=\sum_{n=2}^{K}n\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)^{n-1}\rho^n=\rho \sum_{n=2}^{K}n\left(\frac{\rho\gamma}{2}\right)^{n-1}=-\rho+\rho\sum_{n=1}^{K}n\left(\frac{\rho\gamma}{2}\right)^{n-1}$$